# Production environment not referencing fingerprinted asssets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline

An asset is called in a view as `<%= image_tag('union_15') %>`

In development mode the HTML generated is correct and renders as expected:
`<img src="/assets/union_15-2bd9d905e662bcd012424ffda847b1125dc8637a0b8cee101a174f9db26e838d.png">`

There is an entry for `config/initializers/assets.rb`
`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( initialise.css pdf.css )`

`environments/production.rb` has `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` set [as per the rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-sprockets).

`RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile` was run locally AND on the server.
In addition `.gitignore` was adjusted by commenting `# /public/assets` to ensure the precompiled assets gets percolated to the server.

The deployment process does execute with capistrano in production:

```
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
    ✔ 01 xxx@yy.zz.aa.bb 3.541s
00:34 deploy:assets:backup_manifest
      01 mkdir -p /home/rd/app_name/releases/20231219091853/assets_manifest_backup
```

On the production server the following file was examined
`current/assets_manifest_backup/.sprockets-manifest-e4c8157abe8d8b5916786c943a01c388.json`
to ascertain that the fingerprinting is occuring.  The following JSON entry is found:
`[...]"union_15-2bd9d905e662bcd012424ffda847b1125dc8637a0b8cee101a174f9db26e838d.png":{"logical_path":"union_15.png","mtime":"2023-12-19T09:19:21+00:00","size":2233,"digest":"88b013210661a0b48a30e59ec033c2add1a069ccb72d1d2ce49f9f2c9531963b","integrity":"sha256-iLATIQZhoLSKMOWewDPCrdGgacy3LR0s5J+fLJUxljs="},[...]`

Yet, in production, the HTML does not reference properly, rendering:
`<img src="/images/union_15" />`

This is unexpected given the rails convention.  What is wrong/missing here in the setup?

Comment: do you have `config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback` set to true? use filenames with extensions `image_tag('union_15.png')`

Comment: It is not set.  But that does not mean the default value is not set to true... which between the rails guides and this reference(https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0ae59ea828ed20141af0d4c9ed9130eb47ce55f3/guides/source/configuring.md#L172) gives a rather opaque answer (double negative!)

Comment: default value depends on your rails version. it would explain why you get `<img src="/images/union_15" />` in production instead of a missing asset error. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-assets-unknown-asset-fallback

Answer (score 0):

It turns out two configurations were off-base. The following set the servicing back on course...  The environment variable was non-existent, compilation needed to be set to true.

```
#  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.assets.compile = true
```